# What information is available on the Lamashan holiday of Allbirth?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, lore, religions-and-deities, golarion

I'm looking for information on the Lamashan holiday of Allbirth. I've searched high and low but I was unable to find anything that describes it. Since it takes place at the end of Lamashan, my assumption is it has something to do with Lamashtu and her position as the mother of monsters especially given the name of the holiday. However, I'm unable to confirm this and so now turn to the smart folks here in the RPG stack exchange.

As you can see in this [link to Golarion holidays](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Holidays_and_festivals), the Allbirth link leads to a page that has yet to be created and the text of [Lamashtu's page](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Lamashtu) also does not include any language relating to it. This has been consistent across multiple wikis.

If anyone is able to source a site or campaign setting or other errata on what Allbirth is, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hello and welcome! This looks to me like a very good question, so I have just slightly cleaned it up. You can also revert or [edit] anything I may have changed that you disagree with. Thank you for the contribution and I hope you find the answer you seek here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There is no information about Allbirth

Even if you look into the [Inner Sea Gods](http://paizo.com/products/btpy94wj?Pathfinder-Campaign-Setting-Inner-Sea-Gods-Hardcover), it has no description or clarification of what that holiday is about, all we got (p.97) is the following on **Lamashu's Holidays**:

> The cults of Lamashtu celebrate no known regular holidays, though they engage in debauched hedonism to celebrate births, deformities, and demonic visitations. The entire month of Lamashan is sacred to them, not only because it is named for their goddess, but because it represents the transition from fall to winter, a time of year when the weakest offspring die from the first seasonal illnesses.

With a similar text, this is what we got a few years earlier in [Faiths of Corruption](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8odc?Pathfinder-Player-Companion-Faiths-of-Corruption), on **Religious Holidays** (p.30):

> The month of Lamashan is named after the Mother of Monsters, for it is said to be a dark month when unholy creatures spawned in the deadly cold of winter and in the fevers of spring tear themselves from the womb. The faithful of Lamashtu do not celebrate the month in any way greatly different from any other month. Instead, they mark occasions as the mood takes them, gloating over their dying enemies or holding up the latest deformed child as evidence of their goddess’s favor. They live by no set schedule, and instead offer their bloodied hands as often as they deem fit.

The only mentions of *Allbirth* in the books are from the 3.5's [Gods & Magic](http://paizo.com/products/btpy85eh?Pathfinder-Chronicles-Gods-Magic) about Golarion's holidays, which was later replicated to the [Inner Sea World Guide](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8ief?Pathfinder-Campaign-Setting-The-Inner-Sea-World-Guide) almost as is. The fact that this holiday is listed is in direct contradiction with the text of *Inner Sea Gods* though.

That said, there is a high possibility that *Allbirth* was discarded because of lack of interest , as I couldn't even find many topics about it on Paizo's messageboards. But, if you are interested, I found [this article about it](http://oustomiaworld.wikia.com/wiki/Allbirth) on a fan-made (as no source is given) website.